# cannot index a string index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following `df`:

```
d = {'.KS200': {datetime.date(2016, 10, 3): nan, datetime.date(2016, 10, 4): 259.18, datetime.date(2016, 10, 5): 258.99, datetime.date(2016, 10, 6): 261.13, datetime.date(2016, 10, 7): 260.06}, '0001.HK': {datetime.date(2016, 10, 3): 99.45, datetime.date(2016, 10, 4): 99.45, datetime.date(2016, 10, 5): 99.25, datetime.date(2016, 10, 6): 98.7, datetime.date(2016, 10, 7): 98.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
print(df)

            .KS200  0001.HK
2016-10-03    7.00    99.45
2016-10-04  259.18    99.45
2016-10-05  258.99    99.25
2016-10-06  261.13    98.70
2016-10-07  260.06    98.00
```

Now if I try to index:

```
df.loc['2016-10-03']
```

I get a `raise KeyError(key) from err`

Oddly enough when I print:

`print(df.index)` I get `dtype=object` instead of `datetime` so is it a `datetime` or is it an `object` my index ???

Comment: It's not a string: it's a date. Use a datetime object to index it. You explicitly set the values to datetime dates in your first code line even.

Comment: I am printing a portion of a large dataset using `to_dict()` , and it prints `datetime` but I never specify before in my code, whenever a print `df.index` I get `object` as `dtype` . That's the confusion

Comment: @9769953 if it's a `datetime` why `print(df.index)` is equal to `object` ??????

Comment: Because the index can contain any type of object - it just so happens that all objects are of the same type in the dataframe you created.

Comment: The reason for the dtype being `object` is probably the underlying use of NumPy. It should indeed be `datetime.date` (or perhaps a Pandas datetime object). NumPy, however, doesn't know datetimes as standard types. If you look at `df.index.values`, you'll see it's a NumPy array, and `df.index.values.dtype` is also `object`. Possibly a shortcoming of Pandas (might be noted in an issue somewhere even, if you search around).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataFrame doesn't have a string index - it has a datetime.date index.

try

```py
df.loc[datetime.date(2016, 10, 3)]
```

Better yet, create a datetime index:

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Then, your original indexing will work.

Comment: why `print(df.index)` is equal to object then  `Index([2016-10-03, 2016-10-04, 2016-10-05, 2016-10-06, 2016-10-07], dtype='object')` . Shouldn't be `datetime`

Comment: Because you didn't specify a type for the index. Updated my answer for a better solution.

Comment: First you say that my data frame has a datetime index, then you tell me to assign a datetime to my index. Isn't the first statement contradicting the second ???

Comment: No. I did not say your dataframe has a datetime index - I said it has a `datetime.date` index. To convert it to a pandas.DateTimeIndex, use `pd.to_datetime` as specified in the answer. Did the solution work?

Comment: A more precise way to put it is that your dataframe has an index with type `object` that happens to contain `datetime.date` objects.

Comment: hum ok so how can I check the type of objects and index has please ?

Comment: You can iterate through the rows and see what types your index contains. In your case, all index objects are of type `datetime.date`, but Pandas doesn't enforce this - you could add a row with a string index. Since you can have different types in the index (you didn't specify a type at creation).